# Derivability of the solution of $\begin{cases}x' = |x| + \lambda e^{\lambda x} \\ x(0) = 1\end{cases}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\begin{cases}x' = |x| + \lambda e^{\lambda x} \\ x(0) = 1\end{cases}$ it is easy to show that this has a unique solution $X(t,\lambda)$.

I need to show that there is $\mu > 0$ for which $X \in \mathcal{C}^1((-\mu,100) \times (-\mu,\mu))$.

This is not easy to show with the general theorem. How can I show this?

Comment: It is hard to parse your question.

Comment: @copper.hat let me know ho wcan I improve it